# Why are my normal vectors getting thrown off when merging by distance?

Tags: normals

In Blender 3.3.0, I have an FBX file that I have imported:

[image: Fresh fbx]

These are all separate faces, so I use **Mesh > Clean up > Merge by Distance**:

[image: Merge by distance]

As shown above, the Merge by Distance command throws off my normal vectors for some reason. This persists even when doing **Mesh > Shading > Flat Faces**:

[image: Flat faces]

Enabling **Display Normals** shows the correct direction:

[image: Display Normals]

Going to **Mesh > Normals > Reset vectors** corrects the issue:

[image: Reset vectors]

The normals appear to be identical:

[image: Normals]

However, I plan to do this multiple times and resetting the vectors every time I import an object would become quite tedious. I would prefer that the normals not be thrown off in the first place.

How can I prevent the normals on my mesh from getting thrown off when using the Merge by Distance command?

Comment: Not sure why it's happening without seeing your project, but often, blender "changes it's mind" about the inward/outward direction of  normals when merging by distance (in your image, the _Face Normals_ look correct, but that doesn't mean the edge or vertex normals are "playing along" ). I know it may be tedious, but resetting normals can be simplified by the shortcut Shift+N with the whole object selected in edit mode.

Comment: Try the free version of Machin3Tools and see if it helps, just have to hit the 3 key in edit mode [Machin3Tools](https://machin3.gumroad.com/l/MACHIN3tools)

Comment: You need to be looking at face-corner (vertex-per-face) normals, rather than vertex normals or face normals... see answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be related to [reported misbehaviour](https://developer.blender.org/T100334) in the way .fbx import/export handles Split Normals Data.

Here are two identical objects. Both are flat-shaded, have all edges split, and have a *Custom Split Normals Data* layer added in the *Data* tab > *Geometry Data* panel. Both have *Auto Smooth* switched on, so they are using the custom normals.

The one on the left has been exported and re-imported as an .fbx:

[image]

When vertices on both objects are merged, as shown above , the .fbx import appears to interpolate the custom normals at **vertices**, (furthermore, in a way that makes no obvious sense), which, at least to me, is unexpected. You would expect split normals to belong to face-corners, and so survive the merge of vertices without interpolation, as on the right.

**TL;DR**

After merging vertices, clear the faulty split normals in the *Geometry Data* panel.

Comment: I'll hang on a  while for someone to tell me I'm wrong, and then add a link to this post to the related bug report.

Comment: I believe Blender can handle custom normals as face-corner, as vertex data, or even as groups of face-corner data.  When the mesh is manifold, it's clear which is which, but once the edges are split, there's no longer any information about whether a particular custom normal should be face-corner or vertex.  I'm not so sure that this is a situation where there is a right answer, presuming that .fbx uses the simplest methods, where custom normals are all single face-corner.  A "keep normals" operator on merge (or rip, or separate) might be a valuable right-click-select kind of suggestion though.

Comment: Hi @Nathan! Thanks!  OK...  I just thought.. if it was  called 'Custom _Split_ Normals Data'.. then it _had_ to be stored on loops, not vertices. Otherwise it wouldn't be split. Could be just a misleading name..